# What is the meaning of the verse Bhārate Bhātu Bhāratī?

Tags: resource, reference-request, meaning

What is the meaning of the following verse?

> भारते भातु भारती (Bhārate Bhātu Bhāratī)

What is the source of this verse?

Comment: [Bhārate](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/index.php?mode=3&direct=au&script=hk&tran_input=%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%87) ; भातु means SUN  भारती means something close to "people living in India(bharat)

Comment: http://bbbharati.blogspot.com/2007/12/antiquity-and-origin-of-term-hindu.html, I don't think it is a verse but it is the name of this article.